# How send list of entitties via telegram bot?

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I need send multiple entries from my bot to user.

This is solved by repeatedly calling the sendMessage method? Or specific method exist for this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to call API repeatedly, it doesn't support multiple requests in an HTTP request at this time. :(

BTW, you can make a suggestion to [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport).